# How to get the posts published in last two days using WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query, query, date-time

I am trying to loop through all the post to get the top most shared posts on social network. I want to use the `date_query` parameter in the `WP_query` to get the posts of last two days , last 5 days, last 7 days and last 9 days. How can i implement it through using the `date_query` in `WP_Query` 
My `WP_query` is

```
<?php
 $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'order'=>'DESC',
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'date_query' => array(
                     array(
        'after'     => '10 days ago',
        'inclusive' => true,
       ),
     ),
  'orderby'=>'meta_value',
  'meta_key'=>'esml_socialcount_TOTAL'
  );
 $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
 if($the_query->have_posts()) { 
 while ($the_query->have_posts()){$the_query->the_post();
?>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are two ideas for your `date_query` part:

## 1) After `2 days ago`:

If you need posts published after **current time, 2 days ago**:

```
'date_query' => array(
     array(
         'after'     => '2 days ago',  // or '-2 days'
         'inclusive' => true,
     ),
 ),
```

then the corresponding SQL part is:

```
 post_date >= '2014-09-09 17:57:15'
```

if the current date-time is `2014-09-11 17:57:15`.

### 2) After `midnight 2 days ago` :

If you need posts published after **midnight, 2 days ago**:

```
'date_query' => array(
     array(
         'after'     => 'midnight 2 days ago',
         'inclusive' => true,
     ),
 ),
```

then the corresponding SQL part is:

```
 post_date >= '2014-09-09 00:00:00'
```

if the current date-time is `2014-09-11 17:57:15`.

You can than easily modify this to other day periods.

Comment: As i am placing this code , nothing is working , it didn't show my any posts , but as i change it to "before" instead of "after" in the array , it show the data , but the data which is output by this query is not correct

Comment: Hi, do you have posts published during that period?

Comment: i publish the posts within last two days , last 7 days and even i change the time duration to max, but no result

Comment: i have updated the question , kindly have a look on my parameters of wp_query

Comment: Can you post the SQL query? `$q = new WP_Query( $args ); echo $q->request;`

Comment: sure i will , wait..

Comment: output of the request
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS cvr_posts.ID FROM cvr_posts INNER JOIN cvr_postmeta ON (cvr_posts.ID = cvr_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( ( post_date <= '2014-09-10 10:48:15' ) ) AND cvr_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((cvr_posts.post_status = 'publish')) AND (cvr_postmeta.meta_key = 'esml_socialcount_TOTAL' ) GROUP BY cvr_posts.ID ORDER BY cvr_postmeta.meta_value DESC LIMIT 0, 5

Comment: I guess this SQL was generated with `'before' => '7 days ago'`. What does the date part in the SQL look like, for `'after' => '7 days ago'`. You should also try it without the meta query. It's in general good idea to avoid capital letters in meta keys.

Comment: let me check for the after parameter

Comment: NOW IT'S WORKING FINE AS I CONVERT THE UPPERCASE OF THE META KEY TO LOWERCASE

Comment: great to hear it's resolved ;-)

Comment: But there is another issue has been arised, like it should short the posts according the meta value. i have a post which have 10 like in the past 20 days but it is not showing at the top.

Comment: [link to the website](http://pitambra.in). and the post name is "Beautiful Macro Photos Reveal Tiny Insects With Hundreds Of Hypnotizing Eyes"

Comment: I'm not sure what to look at on the site, difficult to debug remotely. It looks like you're dealing with some other problem, but it looks like the `date_query` is working as expected, when we look at the SQL part. Maybe you should post another question? At least I've tested your query and it works fine on my install with (using a shorter lowercase meta key) or without the meta query. ps: it's preferred to use the `meta_query` parameter, when constructing meta queries. You're also using `posts_per_page` as `1` in your query, that's not reflecting the number of posts on your site.