# Query custom meta value - post view and date meta

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I am making my first post view counter. I have stored views in `post-view` meta and latest date meta `post_view_last`. Now I want to show posts from say last 7 days, last 30 days. My query for last 7 days is below but it's not displaying posts. Basic principle-

1. Query post last 7 days `post_view_last`
2. Order post based on post views `post-view`

   ```
   $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'posts_per_page' => '3',
   'post_status'  =>  'publish',
   'meta_key' => 'post_view',// say 200
   'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
   'order' => 'DSC',
   'meta_query' => array(
   'relation'  =>   'AND',
      array(
       'key' => 'post_view_last',//2017-04-14
       'value' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days')), //value of "order-date" custom field
       'compare' => '<=', //show post less than or equal to today
       'type' => 'CHAR'
     )));
   ```

Comment: check this post https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161080/how-to-get-the-posts-published-in-last-two-days-using-wp-query

Comment: Thank you but I am sorry, that is based on post published date . I am not looking for it .But mine is on custom post meta value .

Answer (score 0):

@Sadia
Please, try this once::

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => '3',
    'post_status'  =>  'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'post_view',// say 200
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DSC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation'  =>   'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'post_view_last',//2017-04-14
                'value' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days')), //value of "order-date" custom field
                'compare' => '>=', //show post less than or equal to today
            )
        )
);
```